# Duplicate data from category and productions table with all of subsets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working in ASP.NET VB and SQL Server.

I want to make a copy of all the category and product data along with their subset.

I have a category table : **tbl_category** as below

**id** is identity key

| id | parentid | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | mobile |
| 2 | 2 | tablet |
| 3 | 1 | apple |
| 4 | 1 | samsung |
| 5 | 3 | iphone 12 |
| 6 | 4 | Galaxy S |

And I have a product table to which the latest category is attached. **tbl_productions** as below

**pid** is identity key

| pid | parentid | productname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | iphone 12 mini |
| 2 | 5 | iphone 12 pro |
| 3 | 6 | galaxy S 9 |
| 4 | 6 | galaxy S 10 |

---

Now: For example, I want to make a copy of the mobile category.

This category includes: iPhone and Samsung, each with an unspecified number of subsets.

And to make the data clear, I add the word "duplicate" at the end of their name, and finally the new data will be as follows.

New category data:

| id | parentid | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | mobile |
| 2 | 0 | tablet |
| 3 | 1 | apple |
| 4 | 1 | samsung |
| 5 | 3 | iphone 12 |
| 6 | 4 | Galaxy S |
| 7 | 0 | mobile-duplicate |
| 8 | 7 | apple-duplicate |
| 9 | 7 | samsung-duplicate |
| 10 | 8 | iphone 12-duplicate |
| 11 | 9 | Galaxy S-duplicate |

And new productions data:

| pid | parentid | productname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | iphone 12 mini |
| 2 | 5 | iphone 12 pro |
| 3 | 6 | galaxy S 9 |
| 4 | 6 | galaxy S 10 |
| 5 | 10 | iphone 12 mini-duplicate |
| 6 | 10 | iphone 12 pro-duplicate |
| 7 | 11 | galaxy S 9-duplicate |
| 8 | 11 | galaxy S 10-duplicate |

**Thanks for pointing me to how I can do this**

Comment: Could you provide some context?  The duplicates,  what’s the purpose?  Are you intended to write this back to the db?  Is there really any reason this question tagged with anything but sql?  What will trigger the duplication?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think you will need to implement it with a loop or recursive loop, basically to create each time new categories and then use their new ids to create their subsets.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make a copy of all the category and product data along with their subset

I think the simplest way is to just insert new rows and add fixed numbers to the ids.  You can do this with `insert . . . select` and by taking into account the maximum id:

```
insert into tbl_category (id, parentid, name)
    select id + maxc,
           (case when parentid > 0 then parentid + maxc else 0 end),
           name + '-duplicate'
    from tbl_category c cross join
         (select max(id) as max_id from tbl_category) maxc;
```

Then do something similar for the productions table:

```
insert into tbl_productions (pid, parentid, productname)
    select p.pid + maxp.max_pid, p.parentid + maxc.max_id,
           p.productname + '-duplicate'
    from tbl_productions p cross join
         (select max(pid) as max_pid from tbl_productions) maxp cross join
         (select max(id) as max_id
          from tbl_category c
          where productname not like '-duplicate'
         ) maxc
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but I was a little confused, I have an unspecified number of categories and subcategories in the category table. I want to copy that category of subcategories and products by giving an ID. For example, I give the ID 4, which is for Samsung, to the query and perform the operation.

Comment: @samuel . . . That is not the question being asked here.  I would suggest that you ask a new question.